# Does Mirth connect 3.6 open source supports HTTP without using SSL manager

Tags: ssl, mirth, mirth-connect

I'm trying to setup a free verion of mirth connect 3.6 version for my client  . I need to setup an interface with HTTP connector. What are the necessary certificates required to connect over HTTPS .
can anyone list out all the checklist  certificates .

Answer (score 4):

No the open source version of Mirth Connect does not directly support SSL.

The means to support SSL in Mirth Connect are:

- MC will natively support SSL for HTTP senders if the recipient presents a certificate chain signed by a root CA trusted by the JVM `cacerts`
- Use a proxy like stunnel, nginx ([Example from the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414240/138200)), or Apache in front of Mirth Connect
- Manually manage the Java keystore and truststore used by the JVM running Mirth Connect. Typically done using `keytool`.
- An open source offering is https://github.com/tonygermano/connect-plugins but it only works for HTTP listeners
- A commercial offering from Zen, https://consultzen.com/zen-ssl-extension/
- A commercial offering from NextGen, https://www.nextgen.com/products-and-services/integration-engine
- Innovar offers an AWS image https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/seller-profile?id=893b7e01-47a8-4b55-b327-99edb31a7324

This listing is more actively maintained at: https://gist.github.com/jonbartels/8abd121901eb930f46245d9ef0f5710e

Disclaimer - I currently have had connections to all three companies with commercial offerings.

Comment: For an example using nginx, see [How can I use HTTP Sender to submit a client certificate without the SSL Manager Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52414240/138200).  Unless you are submitting a client certificate, you will need to remove the `proxy_ssl_certificate` lines.