# How can I use HTTP Sender to submit a client certificate without the SSL Manager Plugin?

Tags: https, client-certificates, mirth, mirth-connect

We have a Mirth server which is not under a support contract which needs to `POST` to a client-certificate authenticated HTTPs service.  Since the certificate is self-signed, [adding it to `appdata\keystore.jks`](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=7591) doesn't seem to work.

How can I explicitly specify a client certificate for a HTTP Sender destination without forking over the big bucks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Mirth connect 3.6 open source supports HTTP without using SSL manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51831891/does-mirth-connect-3-6-open-source-supports-http-without-using-ssl-manager)

Comment: @Freiheit, I agree - they are very similar.  I don't think it is a duplicate since I was talking about a _client_ certificate rather than the more common untrusted server certificate.  The solutions are similar, though.

Comment: my mistake. I see that you are asking a narrowly focused question on mutual TLS rather than the broad question from the other user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an nginx reverse proxy.  That way, Mirth only has to connect on HTTP - nginx submits the client certificate.

For windows:

1. [Unzip nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html)
2. Update conf\nginx.conf
3. [Set to start as a service with nssm](http://oss-world.blogspot.com/2015/10/install-nginx-as-windows-service-using.html)

I replaced `nginx.conf` with the below to keep things simple, listening only on http://127.0.0.1:8106/:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:8106;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://upstream-server;

            # To generate a key&crt from pfx:
            # openssl pkcs12 -in client-certificate.pfx -nocerts -out client-certificate.key -nodes
            # openssl pkcs12 -in client-certificate.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out client-certificate.crt

            proxy_ssl_certificate "C:/path/to/nginx-1.15.3/conf/client-certificate.crt";
            proxy_ssl_certificate_key "C:/path/to/nginx-1.15.3/conf/client-certificate.key";
        }
    }
}
```